# Android TextWatcher doesn't work into two edit text consecutively

Tags: java, android

I just want to do that If I enter a grade then It will change to the points field according to entered grade and If I enter a point then It will change the grade filed according to entered point. I added textChangeListener for both editText but when I enter something my app just doesn't response.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/50LYo.png

```
grade.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                if (grade.getText().toString().equals("A+"))
                {
                    points.setText("4.00");
                }
                else if (grade.getText().toString().equals("A"))
                {
                    points.setText("3.75");
                }
                else if (grade.getText().toString().equals("A-"))
                {
                    points.setText("3.50");
                }
                else if (grade.getText().toString().equals("B+"))
                {
                    points.setText("3.25");
                }
                else if (grade.getText().toString().equals("B"))
                {
                    points.setText("3.00");
                }
                else if (grade.getText().toString().equals("B-"))
                {
                    points.setText("2.75");
                }
                else if (grade.getText().toString().equals("C+"))
                {
                    points.setText("2.50");
                }
                else if (grade.getText().toString().equals("C"))
                {
                    points.setText("2.25");
                }
                else if (grade.getText().toString().equals("D"))
                {
                    points.setText("2.00");
                }
                else if (grade.getText().toString().equals("F"))
                {
                    points.setText("0.0");
                }
                else
                    points.setText(null);

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

points.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                if (points.getText().toString().matches("[4]|[4]\\.[0]{0,2}"))
                {
                    grade.setText("A+");
                }
                else if (points.getText().toString().matches("[3]\\.[7][5]{1}"))
                {
                    grade.setText("A");
                }
                else if (points.getText().toString().matches("[3]\\.[5][0]{0,1}"))
                {
                    grade.setText("A-");
                }
                else if (points.getText().toString().matches("[3]\\.[2][5]{1}"))
                {
                    grade.setText("B+");
                }
                else if (points.getText().toString().matches("[3]|[3]\\.[0]{0,2}"))
                {
                    grade.setText("B");
                }
                else if (points.getText().toString().matches("[2]\\.[7][5]{1}"))
                {
                    grade.setText("B-");
                }
                else if (points.getText().toString().matches("[2]\\.[5][0]{0,1}"))
                {
                    grade.setText("C+");
                }
                else if (points.getText().toString().matches("[2]\\.[2][5]{1}"))
                {
                    grade.setText("C");
                }
                else if (points.getText().toString().matches("[2]|[2]\\.[0]{0,2}"))
                {
                    grade.setText("D");
                }
                else if (points.getText().toString().matches("[0]|[0]\\.[0]{0,2}"))
                {
                    grade.setText("F");
                }
                else
                    grade.setText(null);

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Put your code of textChange listner here

Comment: check some error coming or not ??

Comment: onTextChanged call manytimes when you are typing so put your code in afterTextChanged

Comment: @sushildlh  no error. If I add textChange listener for a specific one grade or points then It works fine but If I do for both nothing happen but my app doesn't response.

Comment: yes it should not respond because of your approach first try move code in afterTextChanged and tell it works or not

Comment: @KhizarHayat it doesn't work

Comment: when you type in points edittext then it will change grade edittext and thats why textWatcher of grade execute and it will effects points editText and the loop will execute and app will stuck. is this happening right now right ?

Comment: absolutely right. This is happening

Comment: @MainulHossain  see my answer

Comment: @KhizarHayat It works exactly what I want.Thank you so much.

Comment: You welcome please accept and upvote my answer thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code:

Call setFocus in onViewCreated() method of fragment or onCreate() in activity

setFocus(grade);

setFocus(points);

```
TextWatcher gradeWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (grade.getText().toString().equals("A+"))
                {
                    points.setText("4.00");
                }
                else if (grade.getText().toString().equals("A"))
                {
                    points.setText("3.75");
                }
                else if (grade.getText().toString().equals("A-"))
                {
                    points.setText("3.50");
                }
                else if (grade.getText().toString().equals("B+"))
                {
                    points.setText("3.25");
                }
                else if (grade.getText().toString().equals("B"))
                {
                    points.setText("3.00");
                }
                else if (grade.getText().toString().equals("B-"))
                {
                    points.setText("2.75");
                }
                else if (grade.getText().toString().equals("C+"))
                {
                    points.setText("2.50");
                }
                else if (grade.getText().toString().equals("C"))
                {
                    points.setText("2.25");
                }
                else if (grade.getText().toString().equals("D"))
                {
                    points.setText("2.00");
                }
                else if (grade.getText().toString().equals("F"))
                {
                    points.setText("0.0");
                }
                else
                    points.setText(null);

            }
        };

TextWatcher pointWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (points.getText().toString().matches("[4]|[4]\\.[0]{0,2}"))
                {
                    grade.setText("A+");
                }
                else if (points.getText().toString().matches("[3]\\.[7][5]{1}"))
                {
                    grade.setText("A");
                }
                else if (points.getText().toString().matches("[3]\\.[5][0]{0,1}"))
                {
                    grade.setText("A-");
                }
                else if (points.getText().toString().matches("[3]\\.[2][5]{1}"))
                {
                    grade.setText("B+");
                }
                else if (points.getText().toString().matches("[3]|[3]\\.[0]{0,2}"))
                {
                    grade.setText("B");
                }
                else if (points.getText().toString().matches("[2]\\.[7][5]{1}"))
                {
                    grade.setText("B-");
                }
                else if (points.getText().toString().matches("[2]\\.[5][0]{0,1}"))
                {
                    grade.setText("C+");
                }
                else if (points.getText().toString().matches("[2]\\.[2][5]{1}"))
                {
                    grade.setText("C");
                }
                else if (points.getText().toString().matches("[2]|[2]\\.[0]{0,2}"))
                {
                    grade.setText("D");
                }
                else if (points.getText().toString().matches("[0]|[0]\\.[0]{0,2}"))
                {
                    grade.setText("F");
                }
                else
                    grade.setText(null);

            }
        };
 /*---------- SET FOCUS LISTENERS ON EDIT TEXT--------------------------*/
    public void setFocus(EditText editText){
        editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    if (v.getId() == grade.getId()) {     
                        grade.addTextChangedListener(gradeWatcher);
                        points.removeTextChangedListener(pointWatcher);
                    } else if (v.getId() == points.getId()) {
                        points.addTextChangedListener(pointWatcher);    
                        grade.removeTextChangedListener(gradeWatcher);

                    }  
                }
            }
        });
    }
```